# How to extract global variable __coverage__ value afterEach hook for Istanbul coverage?

Tags: javascript, protractor, mocha.js, istanbul

I have this code in my unit test case file test.js

```
browser.driver.executeScript('if (typeof __coverage__ !== "undefined") {  return __coverage__; }').then(function(val) {
if(val){
  var now = new Date();
  var destFile = process.env.TEST_DIR + "/output/code-coverage/istanbul/" + "protractor-" + now.getTime().toString() + "-collected-coverage.json";
  console.log("Collecting code coverage and save it to " + destFile + ".");
  fs.writeFileSync(destFile , JSON.stringify(val));
} else {
  console.log("No code coverage found.");
} });
};
module.exports.writeCoverage = writeCoverage;
```

That is supposed to extract the js object value from global variable `__coverage__` and write it to a JSON file. It works for protractor test cases but with mocha unit tests, I am hitting this error:

mocha test.js

"after each" hook for "Get Complete Module List":
     ReferenceError: browser is not defined
      at Object.writeCoverage (/home/../src/writeCoverage.js:4:3)
      at Context. (test.js:7:11)

I appreciate the help.
Thanks!

Comment: Protractor is a framework that runs your tests in a browser. Mocha runs them directly in Node. That's why it's failing.